# Unexpected result of checking type of values in a list - with regards to Booleans

Tags: python, types, boolean

When I have a list containing different values, I tried to check the type of each value and got an unexpected output. It was the Booleans True and False which threw me off. Follows the code and the results.

```
trial_set = {1,2,3,4,None, True, False}

new_list = [type(x) for x in trial_set]
new_set = {type(x) for x in trial_set}

print(new_list)
print(new_set)
```

[Strange Boolean Type Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osQtV.jpg)

Questions:

1. Why does the  datatype appear first in the output though they are the last two elements in the list?
2. Why is there only one  datatype in output when I have two Booleans in the list?

I understand that Bool datatype is a substring of integer datatype and return 0 or 1 and I tried to figure this out from that angle but came up empty. Please help clarify.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sets have no order and don't contain the same item twice.

Answer (score 3):

The result is because of the way Python sets work as well as how Booleans work under the hood. Since `True == 1` in python, only a single occurrence of `1` or `True` will appear, in this case `1`.

Also, sets in python are unordered so when you iterate it with a comprehension to make a list, the order is not guaranteed to be as you typed it.